# Why is fileOutputStream throwing exception here?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, exception, fileoutputstream

```
var result = ""
    withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        if (bitmap != null) {
            try {
                val bytes = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, bytes)

                val dir = File( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "ArtAdda")
                dir.mkdirs()
                val f = File(dir , "${System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000}" + ".png")
                val fo = FileOutputStream(f)
                fo.write(bytes.toByteArray())
                fo.flush()
                fo.close()
                result = f.absolutePath

                runOnUiThread {
                    if (result.isNotEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "File saved successfully: $result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                result = ""
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Can anyone please tell me why my code is not working, here i am trying to save the image present in my application inside the dcim folder of my phone

Comment: The exception thrown should be the first place to look and see what's gone wrong. Take a look and see what that says and if you don't understand it you can edit your question accordingly. Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

you may not have permission to write something in that directory. or maybe you didn't add the necessary permissions to manifest. might be this one, but not sure ;

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

try to debug it to see detail error.

and please use more related exception class in catch instead of base Exception class. you can also use multiple catches. try listing the catch of the most specialised exception first, otherwise (e: Exception) will catch all.

```
catch (e : ExceptionClass1) {
 some code
}
catch (e: ExceptionClass2) {  //less specialised than ExceptionClass1
 some code
}
catch (e: Exception) {  //least specialised
 some code
}
```